# How to reach QHD resolution (external display) on MacBook Pro mid 2012 non-Retina

Tags: display, hdmi, resolution, displayport

I have a MacBook Pro mid 2012 non-Retina ([specs](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp649?locale=en_US)) and an [AOC monitor](http://aoc-europe.com/en/products/q2778vqe) with QHD res, but I cannot get it to reach over 1080p. On the Apple page linked before there is this:

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on an external display, both at millions of colors.

But how can I reach that. Right now I am using a Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter and I guess it could be it that limits the resolution. I also used the DVI port instead of HDMI but nothing changed. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Tried display port to minidisplay port and it works!